# Black monitor when using Wayland

Tags: nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, xorg, wayland

I am struggling with Wayland and multiple monitor setup. 
I have a nvidia 1060 3gb,an Asus H170 motherboard and an i5 6600 CPU.
Two of my monitors are connected to the GPU and one is connected to the motherboard.
When using x11 all three monitors are working well, but x11 is very laggy so I wanted to switch to Wayland.
When using Wayland, only the two monitors connected to the GPU are working, and the third one connected to the motherboard is black. It still displays the cursor and I am able to drag windows on it, so the workspace is definitely here, but everything is black.

So far I tried to execute `$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`, but it didn't work.
Does anyone know a solution?

Edit:
With nvidia priprietary drivers, the monitor connected to my motherboard doesn't work either, I use nouveau drivers.

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS x86_64 
Kernel: 5.13.0-30-generic 
DE: GNOME 
WM: Mutter 
CPU: Intel i5-6600 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3GB 
GPU: Intel HD Graphics 530

Comment: It seems wayland with Nvidia is available only with the new 510 driver.

Comment: In my understanding, it is better to use Wayland with x.org drivers. There is even a rule to prevent the usage of Wayland with NVIDIA proprietary drivers. It is written inside `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/61-gdm.rules` and it states `DRIVER=="nvidia", RUN+="/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-disable-wayland"`.

Comment: That *used* to be the case but wayland support has been enabled with the newer drivers.

Comment: I just tried the NVIDIA proprietary driver 510 with Wayland and only the monitor connected to the motherboard worked. One was completely off and one was turning on but it was completely black. The OS didn't detect the monitors connected to the external graphics card either.

Comment: Unless you have some multi-monitor / multi-head feature setting in the motherboard enabled (auto usually don't do it) then you can't mix them anyway.

Comment: Indeed the feature was disabled by default, I had to enable it, but I did it long ago. The 3 monitor setup is working well on windows 10 and is working even on Linux with X.Org and x11. I have issues when using proprietary NVIDIA drivers or Wayland. My main focus is making it work with Wayland and I can't figure out how.

Comment: @nluciano233 did you found work around? I have same mistake I was able to make that work before but now I update last ubuntu and dont remember how I made

Comment: @InitialCrow unfortunately I never managed to make it work as described in the post. My solution was to buy a DVI to HDMI cable and connect all monitors to the GPU.